# Curl command to push tgz file which contains spaces

Tags: shell, curl, api

I am trying to push one tgz package to Artifactory using CURL API but the file contains spaces which are not pushing it. i have below command  Can anyone provide some suggestions ?

```
curl -u admin:pwd -X PUT https://test.todo.com/artifactory/jenkins-transfer/migrate-man/central/central-test data.tgz -T /data5/central-test data.tgz
```

The error is:

```
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 505 ��� HTTP Version Not Supported</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put the items that contain spaces inside of quotes such as:

```
curl -u admin:pwd -X PUT "https://test.todo.com/artifactory/jenkins-transfer/migrate-man/central/central-test data.tgz" -T "/data5/central-test data.tgz"
```

Comment: Devin, I tried this with keeping double quotes still the error is same. The /central-test data.tgz has spaces in between due to that it is failing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822511/10799034

Comment: try replacing the space with a %20

Comment: Thanks But i pass it as variable to folder spaces how can i pass it through. Any idea ? "export folder=$1
curl -u admin:pwd -X PUT https://test.todo.com/artifactory/jenkins-transfer/migrate-man/central/central-"${folder}".tgz -T /data5/"${folder}.tgz"". I am having issue here to pass folder contains spaces. Please help

Comment: you would want something more like 
curl -u admin:pwd -X PUT "https://test.todo.com/artifactory/jenkins-transfer/migrate-man/central/central-test${folder}" -T "/data5/central-test ${folder}"
you are trying to execute a script and pass the folder as an argument?

Comment: I would test that the %20 works with a manual curl request, this script takes one argument and worked to replace each space with %20

`#!/bin/bash

trimSpace=${1//[ ]/%20}
echo $trimSpace
echo curl -u admin:pwd -X PUT "test.todo.com/artifactory/jenkins-transfer/migrate-man/central/…$trimSpace" -T "/data5/central-test$trimSpace"`